# Junit - Testing a method that uses Foreach

Tags: spring-boot, junit

How do I write a unit for the method below?

Basically the **planDetailRepository.findOnGoingModules** method returns a list of **UserStatus** entity
then apply forEach method on that list setting the status to 1 then save the current **UserStatus** entity
to the database.

My idea of testing this is to verify the **UserStatusRepository** save method number of times it's been called.

**planDetailRepository.findOnGoingModules:**

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM UserStatus a join a.planDetail b where b.startDate = CURRENT_DATE AND a.userPlan.id = (SELECT c.id from UserPlan c WHERE c.plan.id = :plan_id and c.user.id = :user_id)")
    List<UserStatus> findOngoingModules(@Param("plan_id") Integer plan_id, @Param("user_id") Integer user_id);
```

The method to be tested:

```
public void updateModuleStatusPerPlan(planId, userId){
        planDetailRepository.findOngoingModules(planId, userId)
                .forEach(userstatus -> {
                    userstatus.setStatus(1);
                    userStatusRepository.save(userstatus);
                });
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the signature of planDetailRepository.findOngoingModules and type of the list returned by this method

Comment: Question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **Mockito** to do it.You can mock planDetailRepository and userStatusRepository and then perform unit testing:

```
@Test
public void testUpdateModuleStatusPerPlan()    {
      List<UserStatus> userStatusList=new ArrayList<UserStatus>();
      //Create new User Status objects and add them to list
      when(planDetailRepositoryMock.findOngoingModules(planId, userId)).thenReturn(userStatusList);
      when(userStatusRepositoryMock.save(Matchers.any(UserStatus.class)).thenReturn(null);
      <<your class object>>.updateModuleStatusPerPlan(planId, userId);//Set any plan id or user id which should be the same as used while mocking planDetailRepositoryMock.findOngoingModules
      verify(userStatusRepositoryMock,times(userStatusList.size()).save(Matchers.any(UserStatus.class));
}
```

Try this and let me know in case of exceptions...

Comment: Although there are some missing parenthesis, fixes it then it works. Thanks.